# What is acceptable scope for this question which asks for all references in Durarara?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Looking through the list of recently closed questions, I found these 2 questions closed by 5 members of the community:

- https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/23448/what-other-anime-are-referenced-in-the-first-season-of-durarara
- https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/23449/what-other-anime-are-referenced-in-the-first-cour-of-durararax2-shou

The user initially asked for all the references in Durarara for all seasons in a different question (can't find the question through the list of closed/deleted posts), which was closed by our moderator krazer with the too broad reason. With the suggestion of krazer to limit the scope of the question to a single season, the user wrote the two questions above.

Are the 2 questions above really too broad? How can we adjust the scope to make them on-topic?

Comment: Personally I don't think it would be that bad with durara. But Imagine somebody asking for the references in the gintama series and other like wise ones. Only within the first 50 episodes would you probably already exceed a 100 series. Maybe a form of Prevailing type of references would do better?

Comment: @Dimitrimx: Yes, for longer series, it's reasonable to ask them in chunks of X episodes. The thing is, a moderator **has already suggested to narrow down the scope to per season, and the poster also complies with the request**. However, the community still feels it's too broad. I would like to hear the opinion of the close voters, and how they want to narrow the scope of the question down in a reasonable fashion, since in-universe list questions are technically on-topic, as per the latest discussion.

Comment: I think these questions should have remained open. They seem comparable in scope to [Which anime episodes of Aria correspond to which manga chapters?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/2249/7579). Granted, it seems I missed the point when I answered that question and it was actually just meant to test some limits and start a discussion, not to really be answered. Still, when I joined the site, the question was open, so I answered it. The chart I made took me about six hours, with the help of some Emacs keyboard macros. I don't know much about Durarara, but...

Comment: ...it seems like these two questions are of similar scope to the Aria question. If someone comes along who loves Durarara and has a wiki reference and about six free hours, they could probably answer these. It might take a long time (a long, long time) before such a person comes along, but I don't think that's a reason for closing the questions.

Comment: @Torisuda: You might want to write an answer to this meta question with that.

Comment: @nhahtdh When I started writing, I wasn't expecting it to get that long, but I'll work it up into an answer.

Comment: I think it's fail on status 3 of [list question](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/348/what-is-the-status-of-list-questions-on-this-site?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

(Based on my original comments on the question...)

I think these two questions should have remained open. If we have a reopen vote on them, I'll vote in favor. They do skirt the edges of reasonable scope, even split up by season, but they seem pretty comparable to [Which episodes of Aria correspond to which manga chapter?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/2249/7579). Granted, it seems I missed the point when I answered that question. The comments by kuwaly and Logan M indicate the question was meant to start a discussion on exactly this issue, and not really to be answered. But when I joined the site, the question was open, so I answered it.

I answered the Aria question by making a huge chart showing how each episode of the Aria anime corresponds to the original manga. It took me about six hours to make it, with the help of Wikipedia to aid my memory and some Emacs keyboard macros to speed up my typing. I don't know much about Durarara, but it seems like these two questions are of similar scope to the Aria question. If someone comes along who loves Durarara, and has a wiki reference and about six free hours, they could probably answer these. It might take a long time (a long, long time) before such a person comes along, but I don't think that's a reason to close the questions. After all, the Aria question sat open for over a year before I answered it.